# Dealing With Different Coding Conventions/Styles In Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, formatting, code-formatting

I'm working on two different projects - both in VB.NET/Visual Studio 2008 (as much as I'd like to move to 2010).

I find I'm confusing the different coding standards that I'm supposed to follow.  IE - Project1 wants variables named in a Hungarian-style notation like 'iSomeValue'; the does not want a prefix.  One project requires an _ prefix on private class-level variables - etc...etc...

Are there any tools I can integrate with VS 2008 that will let me easily swap between pre-defined styles and format my code for me?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't forces *any* style, write it the way *you* want it.  Well, what your team agreed on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

You can set the name format for every type of member declaration, spacing, etc. You can import and export code style settings. You can choose to

a. use the style for every solution you open
 b. share the style with your team for a given solution
 c. store in a file on a per-solution basis.